# ¿Cómo puedo construir esta consulta con valores recibidos en un POST?

Tags: php

```
$DNI= $_POST["DNI"];
$consulta="SELECT DNI FROM `clientes`
where DNI=$DNI ";
```

Tal como está no me encuentra el DNI solicitado, ahora si el dni lo pongo literalmente en DNI=''; si lo encuentra

Está bien construida la parte de

```
where DNI=$DNI ";
```

Comment: Desde HTML lo ponés como `DNI=""` o a qué te referís con eso? Podrías aclarar un poco más el problema y si es posible, compartir un poco más de información.

Comment: esta en php el codigo adscrito,  me refiero que si pongo el where DNI='11223344D', si me lo encuentra

Comment: Te faltan las comillas en `DNI="$DNI"` porque al parecer es un string.

Comment: si lo pongo así me salta error de sintaxis, si lo pongo ".$DNI." me salta al error del principio

Comment: Qué tipo de dato tiene en la DB el DNI?

Comment: es un varchar(9) para poder poner los numeros y letra

Comment: Vamos de nuevo, me parece que tenés un error de tipo, probá con lo siguiente: `$consulta="SELECT DNI FROM clientes where DNI='$DNI' ";`, que es poniendo en comillas simples el `'$DNI'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para concatenar tu variable  puedes hacerlo así:

```
 $consulta = "SELECT DNI FROM `clientes` WHERE DNI='$DNI'";
```

Cabe mencionar que en la forma que lo haces actualmente es altamente vulnerable a inyección `SQL` (escribes directamente lo que recibes en el `POST`) por lo que  lo mas recomendable es usar sentencias preparadas:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos"); //crea una conexion a tu base de datos


 $consulta="SELECT DNI FROM `clientes`
 where DNI=?"; //nota el uso del ? 
 $stm = $conn->prepare($consulta); //preparamos la consulta

 $stm->bind_param("d", $DNI); //pasamos el valor de la variable
 $stmt->execute(); //ejecutamos la consulta
 $stm->execute(); //ejecutamos la consulta
 $resultSet = $stm->get_result();

var_dump($resultSet->fetch_all()); //imprimiendo la salida
```

Comment: puedes agregar la consulta preparada, esto es vulnerable pueden hacer un SQL Injection

Comment: @JackNavaRow si gracias cuando lo escribi lo pense pero lo deje en el portapapeles, ya esta hecho.

Comment: como podría hacer de esta forma,si hay un registro ya en la bd que me avise?

Answer (score 3):

Podrías utilizar consultas preparadas, 1.- mayor seguridad 2.- evitas estos problemas.

Acá un ejemplo

```
$sql = "SELECT DNI FROM `clientes` where DNI= :DNI;";
$sqlST = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

$sqlST->bindValue(':DNI', $DNI, \PDO::PARAM_STR); // PARAM_INT en el caso de que sea entero
$sqlST->execute();
```

Obviamente todo esto teniendo una conexion PDO establecida donde `$this->conn` tengas la conexión.

[Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: pregunta relacionada [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$consulta = 'SELECT dni FROM clientes where dni = "'.$DNI.'"';
```

Comment: Cuidado con la inyección SQL. Este código es vulnerable.

Comment: Por favor lee [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/21) para aprender cómo evitar la inyección SQL. Un saludo.

Comment: claro, pero el solo pidio el por que no funcionaba. deberia usar consultas preparadas. gracias igualmente.

Comment: Con sentencias preparadas o no, deberías agregar un poco de contexto a tu respuesta. Explica por qué tu query funciona y la de OP no.